# Why does WordPress default NOT NULL datetime columns to 0000-00-00 00:00:00?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, datetime

I am perusing my database schema today and see that `datetime` columns from WordPress are defined `NOT NULL` and with `DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'`. In the same database I have other tables (custom work) that use `NOT NULL` `datetime` columns without this default.

I am just wondering what benefit WordPress derives from using this nonsensical default value.

---

References:

- WordPress's database schema https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_usermeta

Comment: This will cause errors in MySQL 5.7 . Raise it with WordPress themselves? ( I don't know where they live)

Comment: [See here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/143405/wpdb-wont-insert-null-into-table-column?rq=1), the reason is because WordPress Database Interface code does not support `null` values.